# coordinates specification for panels

Tags: java, swing

How can I specify the coordinates of the following panel, instead of having it aligned to the center.

I have tried a lot and used different layouts, but still couldn't get it to work. Please help me solving this problem. Thanks!

Here is my code..

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Lesson2 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -198253288329146091L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Lesson2 frame = new Lesson2();
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Lesson2() {

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974584127539186578L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 500);
            }

        };

        contentPane.add(panel);

    }

}
```

Here is an example of how it looks now
https://prnt.sc/moe3al

Here is the final code edited using a nulled layout with a set size

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Lesson1 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -198253288329146091L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Lesson1 frame = new Lesson1();
                    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Lesson1() {

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974584127539186578L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            }
        };

        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setSize(500, 500);

        contentPane.add(panel);

    }

}
```

Comment: Showing us how it looks currently, doesn't tell us how you want to it look. `I have tried a lot and used different layouts, but still couldn't get it to work` - We have no idea what doesn't work means. Each layout manager will do something different. The answer to you question is to use a proper layout manager or combination of layout managers to achieve your desired layout. Without specific requirements we can't give specific advice.

Comment: @camickr your wrong, I have to show how it looks to show what my current code does. And the second thing doesn't work obviously means not as intended. Finally, I don't know which layout to use that is why I came here not for you to tell me to use a proper one.

Comment: `I have to show how it looks to show what my current code does` -  We know what a FlowLayout does. We don't need a picture to show us that. What we need is a picture to show us what you want. `doesn't work obviously means not as intended` - but we are not mind readers. We don't know what is intended.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All Swing/AWT containers use FlowLayout as the default layout manager, which results in the component being centered. If you want more control, you can use [Absolute Positioning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) by calling contentPane.setLayout(null) and setting the component's coordinates via panel.setBounds(), but be aware that it may not handle window resize elegantly.

Comment: (1-) Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Learn how to use the layout managers effectively and don't use a null layout.

Comment: @camickr agreed, but I did answer the OP's question citing an official source. I don't think I deserve a downvote for that.

Comment: Until a problem is solved people don't always know what they are asking. They don't even know what is possible. It is our job to point them in the right direction so they learn to use Swing effectively. The problem in using a null layout causes other problems that a newbie is not aware of. Based on the incomplete information in the question, using layout mangers is the proper solution.

Comment: @camickr Then which layout that enables me to set their coordinates then, I don't know where to look?

Comment: None of them do, only what I suggested above. He's right though, if you provide more info about how you want it to look, we might be able to suggest a solution using one of the provided layouts.

Comment: Okay so I am trying to lay components for an interface viewer so that there are containers and childs and each component has it's own alignment and coordinates.

Comment: Is it absolutely essential that you be able to size and position these components precisely, or do you really just need to right/left/top/bottom/center justify them?

Comment: Then absolute layout is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for all, I have accepted your answer. Can you please look back to my question? I have added the last edited code. Let me know if there is something wrong there.

Comment: *"but be aware that it may not handle window resize elegantly."* That is only the tip of the iceberg as to what won't be handled correctly by abandoning layouts. See also [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Comment: @o6707448, `Then which layout that enables me to set their coordinates then` - you should not be attempting to set coordinates. That is the job of the layout manager. There is obviously some logic that determines when the components should be positioned. That is the job of the layout manager. But without knowing the logic on how you want the components positioned we can't suggest the specific layout manger to use. All Swing components will be a different size on different platforms. Setting specific coordinates on one platform will look wrong on a different platform.